# Interactive Brokers time-in-force order through python api

Tags: python, api, interactive-brokers

Using the Interactive Brokers Python API, I am trying to submit a limit order that is in-force till a certain time of day.

Based on the documentation here https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/classIBApi_1_1Order.html#a04f61266450f61c36fae22946c74a8f3

it looks like the relevant fields are `tif` and `GoodTillDate`.

Modifying an example from here: https://algotrading101.com/learn/interactive-brokers-python-api-native-guide/

I add the two lines

```
order.tif = "GTD"
order.GoodTillDate = "20200827 16:48:00 EST"
```

When I submit an order using this, I get an error window appear in TWS with this message:

"The time or time-zone entered is invalid.

The correct format is hh:mm:ss xxx
where xxx is an optionally specified time-zone.
E.g.: 15:59:00 EST

Note that there is a space between the time and the time zone.

If no time zone is specified, local time is assumed."

Is there an issue with my date and time format?

My full code:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.order import *

import threading
import time


class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):

    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
        super().nextValidId(orderId)
        self.nextorderId = orderId
        print('The next valid order id is: ', self.nextorderId)

    def orderStatus(self, orderId, status, filled, remaining, avgFullPrice, permId, parentId, lastFillPrice, clientId,
                    whyHeld, mktCapPrice):
        print('orderStatus - orderid:', orderId, 'status:', status, 'filled', filled, 'remaining', remaining,
              'lastFillPrice', lastFillPrice)

    def openOrder(self, orderId, contract, order, orderState):
        print('openOrder id:', orderId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, '@', contract.exchange, ':', order.action,
              order.orderType, order.totalQuantity, orderState.status)

    def execDetails(self, reqId, contract, execution):
        print('Order Executed: ', reqId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, contract.currency, execution.execId,
              execution.orderId, execution.shares, execution.lastLiquidity)


def run_loop():
    app.run()


def FX_order(symbol):
    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = symbol[:3]
    contract.secType = 'CASH'
    contract.exchange = 'IDEALPRO'
    contract.currency = symbol[3:]
    return contract


app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, 0)

app.nextorderId = None

# Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

# Check if the API is connected via orderid
while True:
    if isinstance(app.nextorderId, int):
        print('connected')
        print()
        break
    else:
        print('waiting for connection')
        time.sleep(1)

# Create order object
order = Order()
order.action = 'BUY'
order.totalQuantity = 100000
order.orderType = 'LMT'
order.lmtPrice = '1.10'
order.tif = "GTD"
order.GoodTillDate = "20200827 16:48:00 EST" # format "YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss (optional time zone)"
order.orderId = app.nextorderId
app.nextorderId += 1
order.transmit = False

# Create stop loss order object
stop_order = Order()
stop_order.action = 'SELL'
stop_order.totalQuantity = 100000
stop_order.orderType = 'STP'
stop_order.auxPrice = '1.09'
stop_order.orderId = app.nextorderId
app.nextorderId += 1
stop_order.parentId = order.orderId
order.transmit = True

# Place orders
app.placeOrder(order.orderId, FX_order('EURUSD'), order)
app.placeOrder(stop_order.orderId, FX_order('EURUSD'), stop_order)

app.disconnect()
```

Comment: looks ok to me.  I'll test tomorrow. Note EST is correct in IB language but it means America/New York in TZ language so it's ok for EDT as well.

Comment: I can't get it to work, I tried all options I can think of.  Note that other order types (GTC, DAY) work fine so the order is legit.  Must be a bug.  The docs aren't helpful and contradictory in some places.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, I started to think it was a bug as well.

Comment: I know this used to work, I searched https://groups.io/g/twsapi and found people using it in the past (myself included).  I learned (remembered) something new.  Go to TWS->configure->display->settings->show daylight summer time.  It should be unchecked for EST to work year round.  It's technically EDT right now.  However it didn't work for me or even without the timezone (I'm in NY time).

Comment: Right, I don't have this setting checked, and it doesn't work for me without timezone either. I'm in the same timezone you are.

Comment: Also the issue has nothing to do with the parent/child order, it still doesn't work even if I only use the parent order.

Comment: First make sure it's "order.goodTillDate" and not "order.GoodTillDate". Case matters.

Comment: Thanks @misantroop, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The g in `goodTillDate` has to be lower case.

Example:

```
contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = "AAPL"
contract.secType = "STK"
contract.exchange = "SMART"
contract.currency = "USD"

order = Order()
order.goodTillDate = "20200923 15:13:20 EST"
order.tif = "GTD"
order.totalQuantity = 1
order.orderType = "LMT"
order.lmtPrice = 100
order.action = "BUY"

self.placeOrder(self._next_order_id, contract=contract, order=order)
```