# How to automatically cancel an order if it is not filled after a minute?

Tags: python, tws, ib-api

I want to automatically cancel orders in IBKR's IB API if they are not filled after a minute. They are parent orders, so I can't just use cancelOrder after sleeping for 60 seconds or the child order will also be cancelled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a time in force condition when the order is placed.

See https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/order_conditions.html

and [Interactive Brokers time-in-force order through python api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63624209/interactive-brokers-time-in-force-order-through-python-api)

```
order = Order()
order.goodTillDate = "20200923 15:13:20 EST"
order.tif = "GTD"
```

Comment: This is a great answer! It's exactly what I want and the links are helpful, thank you so much!